# Year list in jquery-ui Datepicker - can it start with specific year?

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

The question is the in title. When I am showing the year list in Jquery-UI datepicker, can I control what year the list starts with?

UPDATED CODE

```
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({ 
     changeYear: true, 
     dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy', 
     altFormat: 'dd-M-yy', 
     minDate: '2001-01-01', 
     duration: ''
    });
```

I need the year list to start with 2001. Is this possible with this control? The code above doesn't achieve this.

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate

Comment: Your minDate format must conform to the dateFormat you specify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could accomplish it a couple of different ways:

```
$(".datepicker1").datepicker({ yearRange: "2001:2012", changeYear: true, defaultDate: new Date(2001,0,1)});

$(".datepicker2").datepicker({changeYear: true, defaultDate: new Date(2001,0,1)});
```

​
`datepicker1` includes a `defaultDate` but it doesn't have to. If you leave it out, it will default to today's date and the year select will start with the current year.

Note that `datepicker2` includes the default year range in the year select box.

[yearRange](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-yearRange)

http://jsfiddle.net/ymvNT/

Comment: Thanks, I used the first option. The second one starts with 1991 and defaults to 2001 in the pick list, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `defaultDate` parameter.
[Link](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate).

If you want to set a specific year only, use the `minDate` and `maxDate` parameters (ie `{minDate: '2010-01-01', maxDate: '2010-12-31'}`.  It's all in the documentation.  Give it a read.

Comment: Do you mean, that you are only allowed to pick dates within the year 2001?

Comment: no, what I mean is that the picklist for year inside the datepicker needs to always start with year 2001. Now it starts from 2007.